# PhoneGap Web SQL query not bringing results

Tags: cordova, web-sql

I am developing a phonegap app.  I have the following code:

```
function showSuper()
{

    openDB(function(db){
        db.transaction(function(tx){
            var q="Select * from Supermercado";

            tx.executeSql(q,[],renderSuper, function (){alert("Error executing SQL SELECT");});
        });     
    });
}

function renderSuper(tx,resuls){
    for (x=0;x<=results.length-1;x++)
    {
        var r=results.rows[x];
        alert(r);
        ht=ht+'<li><a href="page2.html" rel="external">';
        ht=ht+'<h1>'+ r.name+'</h1>;';
        ht=ht+'<img src="+r.logo+'"/>';
        ht=ht+'<p>Categor&iacute;a'+r.categoria+"</p>";
        ht=ht+'</a></li>';      
    }   
    $('#lstSuper').listview('refresh');
}
```

Note that openDB is a shortcut for window.openDatabase(). When the renderSuper() function executes, "results" is undefined. I don't get it, I am following the example given in Phonegap's documentation. Anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am struggling to understand your code without comments.

Here is some websql code which selects the highscore from the websql database, hopefully this helps :)

```
var db;

try 
{   
    db = openDatabase('random game', '1.0', 'random game database', 2 * 10 * 10);
    console.log("LOCALDB - Database ready");
} catch (e) 
{
    // Error handling code goes here.
    if (e == INVALID_STATE_ERR) 
    {
        // Version number mismatch.
        alert("LOCALDB - Invalid database version.");
    }
    else 
    {
        alert("LOCALDB - Unknown error " + e + ".");
    }
}

function errCB(err, res) 
{
    console.log("LOCALDB - DB Error: " , err, res);
    console.log(JSON.stringify(res));

}

function createHighscoreTable(tx) 
{
    //tx.executeSql('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS HIGHSCORE'); //get rid of this when finish testing
    tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS HIGHSCORE (id unique, highscore INT)');
    checkHighscoreValue();
}

function checkHighscoreValue(tx)
{
    db.transaction(function(tx) 
    {
        tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM HIGHSCORE', [], checkHighscoreValueResults, errCB);
    });
}

function checkHighscoreValueResults(tx, results)
{
    var len = results.rows.length;
    if(len == 1)
    {
        var highscore = results.rows.item(0).highscore;
        console.log("LOCALDB - Current highscore is "+highscore);
        dbHighscore = highscore;
        calculateScore();
    }
    else
    {
        db.transaction(function(tx) 
        {
            //creates a default highscore of 0
            tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO HIGHSCORE (id, highscore) VALUES (1, 0)');
            console.log("LOCALDB - Default highscore added");
            dbHighscore = 0;
            calculateScore();
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: I found one problem. I had misspelled results in the superRender() function. I also didn't know that I need to do results.rows.item(n) to get to the row, since it's not documented in PhoneGap's docs. Thanks!

Comment: No problem :) The Cordova / PhoneGap documentation isn't great for websql.